# Why does existence of directional derivatives not imply differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

In my notes I have:
$$Df\big|_{\mathbf{a}}(\mathbf{h})=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})}{t}$$
It says that even if this limit exists for all $\mathbf{h}$, we do not necessarily have differentiability. Is this because the $Df\big|_{\mathbf{a}}$ we get from this is not necessarily linear, or even continuous, in $\mathbf{h}?$ Can I say that if the result map *is* linear & continuous then we have differentiability?

---

I ask because I am doing a problem which asks to check differentiability of some functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. One of them is:

$$f(x,y)=xy\left(\frac{x^4-y^4}{x^4+y^4}\right)\qquad f(0,0)=0$$
which I thought was differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$ since $Df\big|_{\mathbf{0}}(\mathbf{h})=0$ for all $\mathbf{h}$, but I am not sure this is enough.

Comment: Unless you specify $f(0,0)=0$, your function is not defined in 0.

Comment: It's worse than that. Even when all directional derivatives exist, and the map $h \mapsto \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a+th) - f(a)}{t}$ is linear, then $f$ can still be discontinuous at $a$. For your $f$, guess what the derivative would be, if it exists, and check whether it satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Consider $f(x, y) = x$ if $x = y$; $0$ if $x \ne y$ at 0.

Comment: Mere existence isn’t nearly enough. The directional derivatives also have to be consistent. E.g., for $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ the tangent lines in all directions must be coplanar. Even that may not be enough, though. Directional derivatives only “look” along straight lines from a point, but for the total derivative to exist you must have the same limit along *all* paths, not just the straight lines.

Comment: Thanks all. @DanielFischer I'm not sure - I would've said $0$ since the directional derivates are $0$, but it looks like it's not so simple. Could you offer a hint on how I could guess the derivative?

Comment: @user329864 If the directional derivatives are $0$ in two ($n$ for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$) independent directions, then $0$ is the only candidate for the derivative. For if the derivative exists, then $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+th) - f(a)}{t} = Df\lvert_a(h).$$ For the given $f$, it's not hard to decide whether it's differentiable at $0$, do we have $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\lvert f(x,y)\rvert}{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0\,?$$

Answer (score 14):

Existence of *every directional derivative* of $f$ at a point $p$ does not even imply $f$ is continuous at $p$. (!) For example, let $E$ denote the parabola $y = x^{2}$ with the origin removed, and let $f$ be the characteristic function of $E$, namely
$$
f(x, y)
  = \begin{cases}
    1 & y = x^{2},\ x \neq 0, \\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
[image: A discontinuous function with all directional derivatives]

Understanding this example thoroughly should clarify your doubts about your assigned question. The point is, for *every* line $\ell$ through the origin, $\ell$ contains an open interval about $(0, 0)$ that misses $E$.[*] Consequently, $f$ is locally constant along every line through the origin, so its directional derivative in an arbitrary direction vanishes.

Conceptually, controlling the behavior of a function along lines through a point need not give control over non-lines through that point. That's why limits at $p$ are defined by looking at the behavior of $f$ in open disks about $p$.

[*] Precisely, for every line $\ell$ through $(0, 0)$, there exists an $r > 0$ such that $\ell$ does not meet $E$ inside the open disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the existence of that limit does not imply differentiability. Existence and continuity of all the partial derivatives of $f$ in $a$ implies differentiability of $f$ in $a$. In your notation, we get the partial derivatives by calculating the limit $Df|_{a}(\textbf{e}_i)$, where $\{ \textbf{e}_i \}$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, I do not recommend this notation, because $Df|_{a}$ often denotes the total derivative in $a$, whose existence you need to prove! $\textbf{If}$ the total derivative $Df|_{a}$ exists, then the directional derivative in the direction of $\textbf{h}$ is given by $Df|_{a}(\textbf{h})$, the total derivative in $a$ evaluated at $\textbf{h}$.

So, to solve your problem, I would recommend calculating the partial derivatives of $f$, and checking their continuity in $\textbf{0}$. For this you will need to calculate the partial derivatives of $f$ in $\textbf{0}$ as well as in a punctured neighbourhood of $\textbf{0}$, that is, in some $B(\textbf{0}, \epsilon)-\{\textbf{0}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A function $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $a \in U$ if there exists a linear transformation $T_a:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$f(a+h) = f(a) + T_a\cdot h + r(h), \quad\text{ where } \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{r(h)}{\|h\|} = 0.$$

So, yes, $f'(a) \equiv T_a$ must be a linear transformation. Try to find a point $x \in U$ such that $f'(x)$ is not a linear transformation, i.e. $f'(x)\cdot (\alpha h + k) \neq \alpha f'(x)\cdot h + f'(x)\cdot k$.

Comment: "And there's a result ..." That's false: Consider $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)\sin (1/(x^2+y^2)).$

Comment: Wait, if that's a counter-example, then this function $f$ has a discontinuous directional derivative and yet it is differentiable. Is that really right? I mean, is your $f$ really differentiable?

Comment: It is indeed. $\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. I see now, thanks. I will fix it... but the reciprocal is true, right? Continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability.

Comment: By "reciprocal" I think you mean converse. Yes, that implication holds.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $\mathbf x$, then the function $\mathbf h\mapsto f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h)-f(\mathbf x)$ will look linear near the origin. However, the existence of directional derivatives in all directions does not ensure that $f$ will exhibit this behaviour.

For concreteness, suppose that $f$ maps $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$ and that $f(\mathbf 0)=0$. Roughly speaking, for $f$ to be differentiable at $\mathbf 0$, we need there to be a linear map $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(\mathbf h)\approx \phi(\mathbf h)$ when $\lVert\mathbf h\rVert\approx 0$. More precisely, we require that
$$
\lim_{\mathbf h\to\mathbf 0}\frac{f(\mathbf h)-\phi(\mathbf h)}{\lVert\mathbf h\rVert}=0 \, . \tag{$\star$}\label{star}
$$
Thus, not only do we require that the remainder term $r(\mathbf h)=f(\mathbf h)-\phi(\mathbf h)$ is “small” in the sense that it approaches $0$ as $\mathbf h\to\mathbf 0$, but we also require that it is small *relative to the size of $\mathbf h$*. This is a rather strong condition that forces $f$ to behave like a linear map near $\mathbf 0$.

If that last sentence is to be taken seriously, then $f$ must share the properties that linear maps have, namely that they respect scalar multiplication and vector addition. For instance, it ought to be true, in some sense, that $f(2\mathbf h)\approx 2f(\mathbf h)$ for small $\mathbf h$. The natural way to make this condition precise is to ask that
$$
\lim_{\mathbf h\to\mathbf 0}\frac{f(2\mathbf h)-2f(\mathbf h)}{\lVert \mathbf h \rVert}=0 \, ,
$$
and this does indeed hold, provided that $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf 0$ (exercise!). However, even if the directional derivatives in all directions exist, it is still not guaranteed that $f(2\mathbf h)\approx 2f(\mathbf h)$ will hold for small $\mathbf h$. See Andrew’s example, for instance.