# Are all the partial derivatives of a function continuous if the function is continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

We know that a discontinuous function can have continuous partial derivatives everywhere.

However, if the function is contiunous, can we conclude that the partial derivatives are contiunous?

To me it seems like a handy fact because, say, if there is a case-defined function, and we found the function is contiunous, when we try to compute its derivatives, we don't need to compute it again using the definition at the turning points.

Thank you!

Comment: Something like $|x|$?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen The existence of all partials implies continuity in *each* variable when holding the others at fixed values, but does *not* imply multivariable continuity. The standard example would be $xy/(x^2+y^2)$ (defined to be $0$ at the origin). See [this MathSE question about the intuition behind it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2312766/26369).

Comment: @MarkS. Yes, i stand corrected. I deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=x^{2} \sin (\frac 1 x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y$. Then $f$ is continuous. It has partial derivatives at all points but $f_x$ is not continuous.

[This is basically a one-variable example but I am presenting it as a function of two variables].